# NTFS formatting disabled while using Gparted in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, usb-drive, ntfs, gparted, file-format

I am using GParted for formatting my usb-device(a pendrive). And, I unmounted my device using the GUI program itself. The device doesn't show mounted anymore.

When I try to format my usb-device`(/dev/sdc1)` with ntfs-format, the ntfs operation seems disabled in the GParted (GNOME Partition Editor) GUI. Rest other options like `fat32`, `ext3`, `ext4`, etc. are already enabled. I think that has something to do with missing ntfs package/library on my system.

Does anybody know which extra package(s) is to be installed for the same for CENTOS 7? (fedora package)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, finally I got the solution. Though I was already having package ntfs-3g previously installed, it was not sufficient enough for formatting of the usb-drive in ntfs-format.

One needs to install [ntfsprogs --- a subpackage of ntfs-3g](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/ntfsprogs) for enabling the ntfs-format type partition in GParted.

I installed it using

```
sudo yum install ntfsprogs
```

> The ntfsprogs package currently consists of a library and utilities
>   such as mkntfs, ntfscat, ntfsls, ntfsresize, and ntfsundelete (for a
>   full list of included utilities see man 8 ntfsprogs after
>   installation).

Comment: Worked for me in Rocky Linux 9 with `sudo dnf install ntfsprogs`: now I can format in NTFS using Files or Disks.